# Safari extension - why can't I call a page's function? It works from the console

Tags: javascript, safari-extension, safari-web-inspector

I have a safari extension that adds a button to the top left of a page. And all I want it to do is call a javascript function that is defined in the original page when I press that button.

When I try this, I just get back "Can't find variable: reorganizeData"

However if I call reorganizeData() from the console it works perfectly.

I am 100% sure the page is fully loaded. Iv'e even tried putting a 10sec delay on it.

Comment: I've got a feeling this will be an issue with [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and there probably won't be much you can do about it. The console is not really a fair test and isn't representative.

Comment: @phuzi - You really think it might be an S-O P issue? I thought that was more about ajax calls. How does it work when you load jQuery from a CDN? Maybe it's just one way?

Comment: I got around it the lamest way I could think. I inject an image with the code attached in the images "onload"

Answer (score 2):

Your extension's injected script is implicitly namespaced by Safari to protect it from the document's namespace (and vice-versa). That's why the injected script can't call functions declared in the document.

To get around this, your injected script can insert a `<script>` tag into the document. You could have the inserted script add a `click` event handler for your button, which would call the desired function.

Example:

```
var myScript = document.createElement('script');
myScript.textContent = `
    document.getElementById('my-button')
      .addEventListener('click', functionIWantToCall);
`;
document.body.appendChild(myScript);
```